# raw html header with printjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, wkhtmltopdf, printjs

I am using the print js library to export tables in my application.
I need to put a header when exporting each page. Now when I use the json type as follows

```
  let someJSONdata = [{
    name: 'name',
    email: "fda@daa.com",
    phone: "46228156"
  }];
  let url = 'urlstring';
  let rawHTML = `
  <div id="header">
  <img src="${url}"  alt="">
<div class="parraf">
<h3 style="margin:0px"> title </h3>
<h5 style="margin:0px"> subtitle </h5>
<h6 style="margin:0px"> description </h6>
</div>
</div> <br>`;

  printJS({
    printable: someJSONdata,
        type: 'json',
        properties: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
        header: rawHTML,
        style: '#header {   display: flex; } #header img { max-width: 120px;} .parraf { width: 100%; padding: 0px; text-align: center;  max-height: 80px }'
  });
```

** This works well. The thing is that for my situation I am exporting directly to html so the code would look like this: **

```
   let url = 'pathhere';
    let rawHTML = `
    <div id="div_toexport_from_html">
    <img src="${url}"  alt="">
  <div class="textos">
  <h3 style="margin:0px"> INSTITUTO TECNOLOGICO DE SONORA  </h3>
  <h5 style="margin:0px"> ADMINISTRACION DE PERSONAL </h5>
  <h6 style="margin:0px"> Reporte de permisos </h6>
  </div>
  </div> <br>`;

printJS({
      printable: 'div_toexport_from_html',
      type: 'html',
      header: rawHTML,
      style: '#div_toexport_from_html { display: flex; } #div_toexport_from_html img { max-width: 120px;} .textos { width: 100%; padding: 0px; text-align: center;  max-height: 80px; color: #0b6db5; } ',
      targetStyles: ['*'],
      maxWidth: setMaxWidth,
      ignoreElements: viewtoIgnore
    });
```

the bad thing is that it does not correctly rander the html but takes it as a normal text string.
Could it be possible or in what way can it be operated this way?

In summary
The route in this case I put it as a reference that the real url would be placed there. The issue is that I don't know if the printjs library in the options to export allows the following:

```
var printTypes = ['pdf', 'html', 'image', 'json', 'raw-html'];
```

When using the 
`type = 'json'` 
correctly rander the header that is passed through a raw-html string. However, when using the 
`type = 'html'` 
which is my case, it does not correctly rander the specified raw-html string since it takes it as if it were a normal text. 
Maybe that way the library works. Who knows?

Comment: I am not sure but, replace `${url}` with a real URL or `#`, also take in count that your html should be well formed <div> should have </div>

Comment: Thanks @Juan Caicedo  I have edited the question a bit to explain myself better